# Advanced Custom Fields syntax error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I am editing a wordpress theme to add two fields to a slider plugin. I am using advanced custom fields to do this since I don't know PHP too well.

added customheader-img and big-descrip

```html
$videobg_container .= '
<li>
  <div class="slide-container container text-'.$videobg_alignment.'">
    <div class="slide-content page-scroll" style="vertical-align:'.$videobg_vertical_alignment.';">
      <div class="customheader-img">$image = get_field('.$custom_header_image.');</div>
      '.$videobg_description.$videobg_title.$button1.'
      <div class="big-descrip" <?php the_field( 'Subtext'); ?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>'; }
```

The code above spits out a syntax error. If I change the single quotes to 
double quotes ('Subtext') to ("Subtext") it doesn't error out but the content I add to the custom field doesn't show up.

Any ideas what I can do here?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to display the image from the database which you have uploaded using acf ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To get Image field using ACF

```
$image = get_field('image');
```

Use **print_r($image);** and see to that there are multiple dimensions of the image uploaded and you could display based on the key values of the array
// each image contains a custom field called 'link'

```
$link = get_field('link', $image['ID']);
```

At last you can have the image as `<?php echo $image['url']; ?>`

> To get the text or some other contents from ACF

```
$variable = get_field('field_name');
```

Another Important thing is that you have to use render of the variable to print the image that you have obtained
Usage of **print_r()** will lead us to display the image as per our resolutions.

For more documentation visit: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$videobg_container .='   
<li>
  <div class="slide-container container text-' . $videobg_alignment . '">
     <div class="slide-content page-scroll" style="vertical-align:' . $videobg_vertical_alignment . '">
         <div class="customheader-img">' . get_field('custom_header_image')['url'] .'</div>
       '.$videobg_description.$videobg_title.$button1.'
        <div class="big-descrip">'. get_field('Subtext'). '"></div>                     
    </div>
  </div>
</li>';
```

For more info how to query a image ACF field you could read in [ACF docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Comment: `get_field('custom_header_image');` will result only in an array right. Then how the image will be printed onto that place ?? You have to specify along with the image dimensions that we will find in our array values like `$thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];`

Comment: I editer and added 'url' after get_field since the image url is in $image =get_field('custom_header_image'); echo $image['url'];

Comment: This still gives me a syntax error. For some reason it does not like the single quotes...is there an alternate way to write this without single quotes?

Comment: Could you provide a link the a page with the error?

Comment: Which page there i could see the error? I don't see a error